# How to retrieve first and last name from MailChimp

Tags: mailchimp

Is it possible to retrieve first and last name from MailChimp API? According to he documentation it is possible to get the email address using `listMembers(string apikey, string id, string status, string since, int start, int limit, string sort_dir)` but I looked everywhere and all I found are ways to add Email, FNAME and LNAME when adding a new subscriber but the question in place how do I retrieve that info back.

Comment: Where do you want to get that information back, in a campaign or on your webpage?  If you want that information in a campaign you can just use Mailchimp's default merge tags.  I think first name/last name would be *|FNAME|* and *|LNAME|*  http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/all-the-merge-tags-cheatsheet

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after hours of pulling hair here is what I found and I hope it saves someone time. @dcc yes you were right FNAME AND LNAME are the key in here

```
    $retval = $this->mail_chimp->lists();

    $list_size = $retval['total']; //int
    $list_data = $retval['data']; //array

    //go through all Lists
    foreach($list_data as $list){
        $list_id = $list['id'];

        //get members of this List
        $members = $this->mail_chimp->listMembers($list_id);

        //go through all members
        foreach($members['data'] as $member){
            $user_info = $this->mail_chimp->listMemberInfo( $list_id, $member['email'] );

            // catch email, first name, and last name of this member
            foreach($user_info['data'] as $info){
                echo $info['euid'];
                echo $info['merges']['FNAME'];
                echo $info['merges']['LNAME'];
                echo $info['merges']['EMAIL'];

            }
        }

    }
```